# HTA Time Picker

Tags: datepicker, timepicker, hta

I'm building an HTA (userform) and would like to add a Time Picker but have been unsucessful getting something to work.  I'm using the JQuery Date Picker successfully, but their website does not have any reference to using a Time Picker, or manipulating the date picker to show the time. Since HTA is a stand alone applicaiton I know my options are limited, but hopefully someone knows what I'm missing here.  Thanks!

```
<HEAD>

<meta charset="utf-8" />  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.ui-datepicker {
    background: #035c7e;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    color: #EEE;}
</style>

<script>  
$(function() {    
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();  }); 
</script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
Shift Date: <input type="text" name="StartDate" id= "datepicker1" size="8">
Start Time: <input type="text" name="StartTime" id= "" size="8">
etc.
</BODY>
```

Answer (score 1):

Download the 2 external js-files and include them from local filesystem.